# Assign Excel number format from string variable

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I create an Excel workbook using a PowerShell script. The workbook consists a chart with two axes. The number format for one axis shall be set to a localized custom date-time-format.

The standard format is prepared as a shorter version of the long date format:

```
[string]$fmt = "MM/dd hh:mm"
```

The script evaluates the automatically created axis NumberFormat member and uses a different string if the NumberFormat is already localized:

```
if ($axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat.Contains("JJJJ")) {
  $fmt = "TT.MM. hh:mm"
}
```

Finally the script tries to assign the string to the axis member:

```
 $axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = $fmt
```

But this format is not accepted by the axis object. If I read back the value I get "Standard".

Even this code resets the number format to standard:

```
 $fmt = $axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat
 $axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = $fmt
```

How can I set a custom date-time-format?

**Edit:**
The standard date-time-format for the localization DE-DE is "TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm". Excel uses this as default if the chart is created. That format is valid for DE-DE even it may be unknown in your Excel localization.

Comment: what is this number format `TT.MM. hh:mm`, it is not a valid format in Excel.

Comment: @cyboashu Your comment is right for the non localized (or en-US) version of Excel. If the display language is set to another value, you may get other valid format strings.

Comment: @cyboashu That date-time will be displayed as "27.12. 13:45" if you entered this with the GUI. But I need to setbit by script.

Comment: Display language is "German (Deutschland)" also shown as DE-DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NumberFormatLocal` instead of `NumberFormat` to get/set a localized format:

```
$axis.TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = $fmt
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with number format.

You need to set your axis type to Text before you can add a date to it and apply custom format (with time bits) on top of that.

This works:

```
$chart.Axes(1).CategoryType =2
$axis= $chart.axes(1)
$axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM. hh:mm"
```

where as if you leave the Axix category to default/automatic, the number format doesn't work as expected.

```
$axis= $chart.axes(1)
$axis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM. hh:mm"
```

You have a time format in your number formatting and apart from scatter charts nothing else support that on an axis. So you need to first change your axis type.

Comment: If I read the CategoryType instead of setiing it, I get already the value 2. That's no surprise, because the data column the is the source for the x-axis is already a list of date-time values.  Well with that background I could not get any help from your answer. Thank you, anyway.